# Where to find asm/unistd.h

Tags: gcc, 32-bit, 18.10, assembler

When trying to build [jonesforth](https://github.com/nornagon/jonesforth/), which is a 32-bit GNU Assembler program, on Ubuntu 18.10 64-bit, I get the following message:

```
~/src/jonesforth $ make
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static  -o jonesforth jonesforth.S
jonesforth.S:1154:10: fatal error: asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/unistd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:11: jonesforth] Error 1
```

The source has the following lines:

```
//#include <asm-i386/unistd.h>  // you might need this instead
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

When I try using `asm-i386/unistd.h` instead, it runs into the same issue.

Is the best course of action to install more headers via `sudo apt install linux-headers...`? If so, which should I go with? Should `linux-headers-generic` be sufficient?

Or, should I change the header that `jonesforth.S` is referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need [`linux-libc-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/linux-libc-dev/filelist) or [`linux-libc-dev-i386-cross`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/linux-libc-dev-i386-cross/filelist) (and use `CFLAGS="-I ...` accordingly).